# Identify risks from 100 case studies

Tags: risk-management, project-management-style, risk

I want to identify risks from 100 case studies of past construction projects. What the most relevant documents that I need to consider that would save my time.

Thank you in advance,

Mustafa

Comment: Could you tell us which documents you have available on the case studies Mustafa? Different projects have different documents available depending on the nature of the project and the approach that was taken. e.g. Project Plan, Project Brief, Project Closure Report, etc.

Comment: You may find this tool useful: [0rsk.com: Cause + Risk + Effect](https://www.yegor256.com/2019/05/14/cause-risk-effect.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am not in construction but here's what I would suspect:

```
Risk and Issue Log
Change Log
Contract Performance Reports
Quality Surveillance Reports
Audit Findings
Engineering Reports
Architecture Reports
Local Inspections Findings
```

and finally Lessons Learned or whatever the equivalent is in this industry.